# Set a pointer to pointer in c++/cli

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a managed class and would like to set the native class in the `create()` method.

```
ref class ManagedClass {

private:
    NativeClass* ptr = nullptr;    

public:
    void create()
    {
        NativeClass nativeClass;
        nativeClass.set(0);
        this->ptr = &nativeClass;
    }
};
```

However, the `nativeClass` is deleted when `create()` was run. And hence `this->ptr` become empty. How to make the local variable `nativeClass` does not be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables cease to exist when the function in which they are defined returns, and any remembered pointer to such a local variable becomes invalid. This is no different in C++/CLI vs. unmanaged C++.

To create an object that persists beyond the `create` call, allocate it dynamically and save a pointer to it with `ptr = new NativeClass();` (then don't forget to `delete ptr;` when no longer needed).